# How to Map Lists in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, list

Hi I am working in c# and I have two list as below

```
public class Table1
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int mid {get;set;}
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string FirstData { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SubType { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; } 
}
```

```
public class Table2
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int mid {get;set;}
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string DateRange { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the final List I want

```
public class FinalTable
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int mid {get;set;}
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string FirstData { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SubType { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; } 
    public List<Table2> table2List { get;set;}
}
```

So, I have some data in `Table1` and `Table2`. I am retrieving these two lists from different sources and finally I have to prepare list in the form of `FinalTable`.

In table `Table1` for each `mid` and `channelid` there will be corresponding values in `Table2` also. This is basically one to many relationship where foreach `mid` and `channelid` in table1 there will be multiple entries in `Table2`.

So, after mapping finally I would like to show data in the form of `FinalTable`. FinalTable has property `table2List` to accomodate table2 data. I can do this by writing multiple or nested foreach loops but what would be the best approach to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Have you looked at [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Linq for this. Your code would look like:

```
var t1 = new List<Table1>(); // your real data as a list
var t2 = new List<Table2>();


var result = t1.Select(t => new FinalTable {
    Id = t.Id,
    mid = t.mid,
    // ...
    table2List = t2.Where(x => x.mid == t.mid && x.ChannelId == t.ChannelId).ToList()
});
```